# Transition style for UITabBar in Storyboard

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I see option **Transition style** and 4 types of transition — Cover Vertical, Flip Horizontal... when selecting TabBar Controller in Storyboard.

If I change this option nothing happens. Why? And how can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know transitions for changing the view in a `UITabBarController` are not allowed, as it is no sege but a relationship (between TabBarController and its tabbed ViewControllers) in storyboard.

So setting up a transition style in the tabbed ViewControllers has no effect. Setting up the transition style of the TabBarController determines how it is presented itsself, so it may have an effect!

This post may help to manually generate animated transitions:
http://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/animated-transition-between-tabbars-view-on-iphone/